# Rails: Migrating database From Postgres to MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

My project was created using PostgresSQL but we really intend to use MongoDB, what should I change in order for that to happen?

A lot of scaffolding already took place, so we are trying to savage any of the work already done...

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing your exact project scope and seeing what you have already done. But if you really want to benefit from MongoDB, you likely need to start your database abstraction layer from scratch. MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for relational databases. You will need to reconsider your whole data model.

Comment: @Philipp we actually modelled everything for Mongo, adding `Document` to the relevant classes and etc, but when creating the project, for example, we forgot to use `--skip ActiveRecord`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove database adapter gems from your Gemfile (mysql2, sqlite3, etc.)
2. Change your `config/application.rb`

Remove require `'rails/all'` line and require frameworks you want to use, for example:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

*NOTE: You should be using the require snippet from the `rails/all.rb` file that is current with your version of Rails without the active_record railtie. Here is a link to `rails/all.rb` on the [Rails master branch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb).*

3. Delete your `config/database.yml` file, `db/schema.rb` and migrations (if any)
4. Delete migration check in `test/test_helper.rb`
5. Delete any `ActiveRecord` configuration from your config/environments files

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never! This should come in handy to somebody, someday!!!!

The following python-based migration framework does the job.

https://github.com/datawrangl3r/pg2mongo

Coming to the performance, the migration of each JSON object is dynamic and there shouldn't be any memory lock issues when you use the above framework.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation I also I have to face . I am adding some additional points to above answer .

1) Create a file in initializers and put this code

```
Mongoid.load!(Rails.root.join("config/mongoid.yml"))
```

2) You have to remove from every model which are inheriting from ApplicationRecord and delete the  application_record file.

3) If you have installed devise so you have to change 
  **From **

```
 require 'devise/orm/active_record'
```

**to**

```
require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
```

4) If you are using carrierwave so in gem file you have to replace

**From**

```
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

**To**

```
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
```